# How do I prevent a server from joining the NLB when it starts up?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, nlb

I have a problematic Windows Server 2003 box (MOSS 2007) that caused problems so we shut it down.  When we bring it back up it joins the NLB (one other server) and causes problems.  We tried shutting down IIS on the troublesome box but the problems persisted until we shut it down again.

We would like to bring up the server without it joining the NLB.  How do we accomplish this?

EDIT: I am not an admin, just trying to help our guy out.  I'm assuming that if a box is powered off then it doesn't show in NLB Manager, and if it doesn't show, you can't set its properties, remove it from the group.  Does that sound right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to set the default state to Stopped.  To do this, go into the NLB properites on the network card.  On the Host Parameters tab, you can choose the drop down next to Default State.

---

**Update for Edit**
You'll need to bring the server up to change the NLB settings.  After that you can reboot it as needed without it joining the cluster.

[NLB Config Screen http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5923a68d0e.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5923a68d0e.png)

Comment: As a side note: On W2K3 the recommended method of managing an NLB cluster or member is to use NLB Manager and not to edit the NLB settings directly on a cluster member.

Comment: That box isn't showing in NLB manager even after being brought up.  I'm in over my head at this point :)